# Merge Sort Problems In Python

Tags: python, sorting, merge, mergesort

So I'm trying to teach myself how to write a merge sort but for whatever reason I can't seem to make it work.

```
    def merge(left, right):
        result = []
        i ,j = 0, 0
        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            if left[i] <= right[j]:
                result.append(left[i])
                i += 1
            else:
                result.append(right[j])
                j += 1
        result += left[i:]
        result += right[j:]
        return result

    def mergesort(numlist):
        if len(numlist) < 2:
            return numlist
        middle = int(len(numlist)/2)
        left = mergesort(numlist[:middle])
        right = mergesort(numlist[middle:])
        return merge(left, right)
```

Every list I feed into the sort then attempt to print just comes up the exact same with no changes

Comment: how do you use your function? `print(mergesort([3,4,1,1,6,2]))` works for me. you have to check return value, not original `numlist`, which isn't changed.

Comment: mergesort(list_of_numbers) should return that list but sorted from least to greatest

Comment: I get `[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]` from your exact code. Good enough for you?

Comment: In which case you're throwing away the value by not assigning it to anything. `list_of_numbers = mergesort(list_of_numbers)` so that you can retrieve the sorted list. It works fine but it doesn't sort in place.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'm relatively new to programming so these kind of bone headed mistakes are common with me.

Answer (score 0):

Answering so this can be closed though it was fixed in comments with the help of @Jean-François Fabre.

Your current code works fine but it does not sort the list in-place. In the case of sorting a list called `list_of_numbers`, you need to assign the result back to `list_of_numbers`:

`list_of_numbers = mergesort(list_of_numbers)`